# How do I change the default SELECT TOP 1000 query to use * instead of each field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SSMS 2008 R2, we have the default Select top 1000 and Edit top 200 queries from the right click menu.  I've seen where you can change the # of rows it returns in the options.

What I'm after is, can I tell it to do a SELECT * instead of expanding and including every field?

It's not a performance issue or anything, just an annoyance when querying tables with more than about 5 fields, I'd like do a select *.

For example, if I have a table with the following fields:

- FirstName
- LastName
- Birthday
- City
- State
- Zip

When I right click on this Persons table and choose the "SELECT TOP 1000 ROWS" Menu, I'd like the query that is run to be

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *  FROM People
```

and NOT

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FirstName, LastName, Birthday, City, State, Zip FROM People
```

**EDIT** I suspect there isn't really an answer to this, but thought I'd see if anyone figured it out.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM MyTable`. Doesn't this work?

Comment: Updated the question to provide more clarity, I know how to do a SELECT *, I'd like to customize the menu behavior.

Comment: Why is this an annoyance? Surely it makes it easier if you subsequently decide that you only want a subset of the columns? The only thing that appears customisable is the number anyway so I think you're stuck with it!

Comment: I don't think why it's an annoyance is relevant. It would be nice to have a simple query show up. I would like to know if there is an answer to this as well.

Comment: It's an annoyance like a tag on the back of your shirt.  Sometimes you want to see the wash & care conditions, but most of the time you just want to wear the shirt.

Comment: You can't. SSMS knows that SELECT * is bad practice, and doesn't do it from the menus (why should it encourage bad habits to develop?). If you want to use SELECT *, your query should be short enough to type it yourself.

Comment: @Ken, if you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way of customising the native SSMS functionality. However you can use the [SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) addin "Custom Scripts" for this type of thing.

[image: Screenshot]

(Though to be honest Selecting the columns and typing `*` might be as quick as navigating the menu)

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I marked this as the answer, because even though select * is pretty quick to type out, this tool has a lot of other uses, and I never knew it existed.

Comment: @taylonr - Agreed. The ability to search historic queries you have executed makes it worth installing alone IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Why would the developers of SSMS want to encourage a poor practice. Since select * is a very poor practice indeed, why would they want to encourage it?

I can see not wanting to write all the fields in a quick non-production query but since it is doing that for you, why would you not want it do do it correctly?

Comment: In deed, in our production queries we don't do Select *... this is when I'm investigating something quick and dirty in a dev or test DB, inside of mgmt... I just like the more succinct text of SELECT *, but I understand not wanting to encourage bad habits.

Comment: For me it would just make the window a little more readable, instead of having all that clutter.

Comment: It's a poor practice in production, but when you're experimenting, it's just clutter. Do you by chance grab those automatic queries and slap them into production? I just don't use the menu and fallback to writing `SELECT * FROM X` by hand since it's really short.

Comment: I never, ever write those automatic queries.

Answer (score 1):

It's against best practice so SSMS won't do it.

Your best bet is either to delete the specific columns and replace with `*`, or just leave it as it is considering the default is to select all the columns for you anyway...

Putting the cursor after the `TOP n` and doing `Ctrl-Shift-End`, `Shift-Up`, `*` doesn't take ages, but I do understand that when you're testing it makes very little difference to use `*` over the full column specification and it keeps everything tidier.

If you combine [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) with SSMS IntelliSense you could probably make it quicker to type than to scroll, right-click and select.

Comment: For me it is a pain to delete all the columns and replace with `*` every time I open that window up. In this day of plugins and automation, you would think they could give the power of manipulation to the user. Best practices are best practices, but it shouldn't force them on us if we have our own reason not to use them.

Comment: @Eli - i know what you mean, I was just in the process of updating my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: "It's against best practice so SSMS won't do it" - that's just arrogant BS. (From SSMS, not Town.) When the table has lots of columns, highlighting all the columns to delete them is not a trivial task. It's already a pain in the ass that I can't go straight to the SQL view, I *have* to wait for it to load some number of utterly useless rows before it'll deign to let me edit the query, because setting the number of rows returned to zero causes it to, get this, return **ALL** of the effing rows.

Comment: SSMS Tools Pack, although it has a small fee, is a nice way to do this as suggested above.